# AxWindowsMediaPlayer size in WPF applications

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am using an `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` in a `WindowsFormsHost` in a WPF application.

I'm having problems with sizing the control.

1. I need to hide the video part, and keep only the part with buttons and seek bar. (since I run audio)
2. I need to adjust the `WindowsFormsHost` to only display this part.

I tried to resize the `WindowsFormsHost` manually so that it only shows the required part, but when I tested the program on different pc's it wasn't displayed properly. Some parts from the control were cropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you want to hide the video with the uiMOde

```
awWindowsMediaPlayer.uiMode= "invisible";
```

But, this hide controls too...

For me, you have two solutions:

the first, you create your axWindowsPlayer form with 45pixel of height for display just the controls button.

the seconds, you hide all the form, and create all your button...

you've acces at the controls button with : (play button for sample)

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

And you've acces to the settings with : (volume for sample)

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer.settings.volume = 25;
```

I also saw that it was possible to define a custom uiMode, but I did not find any information about that...

Comment: It would have been nice if they just made a bool flag like HideUi that you could set to true or false. Oh well, this works at least :)

Comment: @theJerm Using this in WPF it seems really convoluted and hacky compared to traditional WPF controls. I wrote a wrapper to bundle up all the features I'd expect to see exposed on the top level and there you go. All is well.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. Set `uiMode` to `invisible` and define your own buttons (functions are accesable like: `axWindowsMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.stop();`).
2. Set `uiMode` to `mini` or `full` and set height 40. It leaves control without video visible (link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also hide status, bar and controls

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer.uiMode= "None";
```