# AxWindowsMediaPlayer without video display

Tags: c#, axwindowsmediaplayer

I need to use an AxWindowsMediaPlayer control in a c# application to play audio. So I need to hide the video display, and keep only the controls (buttons and seek and volume bars)

Any idea how this can be accomplished?

All I could find is the [uiMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you want to hide the video with the uiMOde

```
awWindowsMediaPlayer.uiMode= "invisible";
```

But, this hide controls too...

For me, you have two solutions:

the first, you create your axWindowsPlayer form with 45pixel of height for display just the controls button.

the seconds, you hide all the form, and create all your button...

you've acces at the controls button with : (play button for sample)

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

And you've acces to the settings with : (volume for sample)

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer.settings.volume = 25;
```

I also saw that it was possible to define a custom uiMode, but I did not find any information about that...

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a better solution. Your first solution: different display settings will need different number of pixels. Your second: What about the seek bar?

Comment: Hi!
Very good question. I know You can search all attributes in your media Collections with 'AxWindowsMediaPlayer.mediaCollection', In your collection, you can search the name of author, the genre, or other attributes... You can find all the collection media search ressources [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, first solution works properly. Please copy this reply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949598/axwindowsmediaplayer-size-in-wpf-applications